# Funciones Recursivas en Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Sera que alguien me puede ayudar con mi problema?

Pues necesito sacar la funcion recursiva de seno (`senos a la -1`) en un programa que estoy haciendo en visual basic, pero al calcularlo y pasarlo a radianes no da el resultado que deberia de dar

```
senoInverso = Math.Asin(1 * 3.1416 / 180)
```

El resultado que me da es= **0.01745**.

Como estoy utilizando el 1 como ejemplo, el resultado deberia de ser 90 pero no lo calcula bien.

Si lo hiciera de esta forma=

```
senoInverso = Math.Asin(1)
```

Me de el resultado que deberia de dar si estoy utlizando la `función seno`.

Alguien me podria decir que es lo que tengo que hace para que pueda obtener el resultado correcto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la fórmula que usas para pasar de radianes a grados es incorrecta. Debes usar `radianes * 180 /pi`.

En tu caso:

```
grados = Math.Asin(1) * 180 / Math.PI ' resultado 90
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!
Me ha sido de mucha ayuda.